# Nil Out package.loaded Every Time?

Tags: lua

Is it good practice to nil out the loaded package every time the script is called? What if the file never changes during runtime? Can I just use require instead of nilling it out first?

```
package.loaded["scripts/common/functions"] = nil                                                                   
require("scripts/common/functions")
```

The functions.lua file is used a lot, so would keeping it in cache be beneficial?

Comment: Nilling out `package.loaded[...]` is used for reinitializing the package instead of returning saved copy of its result from previous initializing.  Whether it is useful or not depends on the package you are using.  For most packages nilling out has no benefit.

Comment: Can it affect performance by reinitializing it every time?

Comment: If you want to reload a file multiple times, use `dofile` instead of `require`.

Comment: @SteveStout - Scarcely.  Except when you are initializing a package in a loop :-)